# JSON to Java Object Mapping in Spring MVC results 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: java, json, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am getting 400 (Bad Request) error when I submit the form. I am using Jackson API jackson-core-asl-1.9.10.jar and jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar.

I am able to receive JSON but unable to submit it.

**myscript.js**

```
var app = angular.module('project', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('projectFormCtrl',["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submitProject = function() {
        console.log($scope.project); //Works fine
        $http.post('saveProject',$scope.project).success(function () {
            console.log($scope.project);
        });
    };

}]);
```

**WebController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveProject", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ProjectDetails submitProject(@RequestBody ProjectDetails projectDetails) {
    System.out.println(projectDetails);
    return projectDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also gone through the same problem of **Bad request**. I resolved it by doing the following code.
You can post an array to a controller by converting it into json string by **JSON.stringify(array)**.
I have pushed muliple Objects into an array using **push()**.

```
    var a = [];
    for(var i = 1; i<10; i++){
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.name = $("#firstName_"+i).val();
        obj.surname = $("#lastName_"+i).val();
        a.push(obj);
    }

    var myarray = JSON.stringify(a);
    $.post("/ems-web/saveCust/savecustomers",{myarray : myarray},function(e) {

    }, "json");
```

**Controller :**
You can use jackson for processing json string.
Jackson is a High-performance JSON processor Java library.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/savecustomers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ServiceResponse<String> saveCustomers(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String myarray) {

        try{
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true); 
            List<DtoToMAP> parsedCustomerList = objectMapper.readValue(myarray, new TypeReference<List<DtoToMAP>>() { });
            System.out.println(" parsedCustomerList :: " + parsedCustomerList);
        }catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Note : make sure that your dto should contain same variable name as you are posting with an array object.
in my case, my dto contains firstName,lastName as am posting with an array object.

**Jackson Dependancy :**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi! receiving JSON as string works perfectly fine. Thanks!
But is there any way that mapping to java object is done automatically?

Comment: Okay! I have done without string now. Problem was my name of variable was not present in my form at frontend.

This problem is now resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [sample](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/contact-rest-services.html) for view Spring MVC configuration to use json mapper.

Comment: I think your Not really answering, u keep it as comment this.

Comment: I can only post answer and this sample is for configure Spring MVC with JSon request